# Is there any algorithm for finding a shape from a point?

Tags: algorithm

Is there any algorithm for finding shape by point? Consider if I have list of polygon, I got 2 shape:

**Shape 1:** x and y

```
[10,10,]
[10,40,]
[40,10,]
[40,40,]
```

**Shape 2:** x and y

```
[40,40,]
[40,80,]
[80,40,]
[120,120,]
```

If I have a point lets say
point 1 with x and y

```
[119,199]
```

That means I choose shape 2,
Is there any algorithm to determine a shape from point?

Comment: Do you mean : Given a point and a list of shapes, find which shape(s) the point belongs to ?

Comment: Your point is not inside either polygon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many different data structures for performing this kind of query - mostly they are tree structures which represent the polygons in a spatial hierarchy of some sort. My personal favourite is the R-tree, which has a [very good implementation in recent versions of the boost libraries](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/spatial_indexes/boost__geometry__index__rtree.html). You build an R-tree from your list of polygons and then it's a very simple (and efficient) matter to perform a query for a given point to see which polygon(s) it lies within.

Comment: rtree is just rectagle isnt it? how about polygon? is rtree can handle it?

Comment: Although the hierarchy is defined by bounding rectangles you can use it for any kind of geometry. The boost implementation makes this quite easy, see e.g. [this example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/spatial_indexes/rtree_examples/index_of_polygons_stored_in_vector.html).

Answer (score 0):

Look at [JTS Topological Toolsuite](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jts-topo-suite/).

It's open source so you can study their code. Look into [Geometry.contains()](http://tsusiatsoftware.net/jts/javadoc/com/vividsolutions/jts/geom/Geometry.html#contains(com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry)) method for your specific question.